# @ContainedIn on field inside @EmbeddedId class

Tags: hibernate-search

My code has a Place and Address classes. Address 1:N Places.

There is one index, **Address Index**.

When the Address is saved, that is ok, works fine. But when the Place is saved, the Index of Address isn't updated.

The problem, maybe is a bug:
**When @ContainedIn is on field inside @EmbeddedId class, that doesn't work. The intern mechanism isn't notified, hence index isn't changed.**

I've tried some workarounds:

- Updated index manually `fullTextSession.index(obj)`. -> DON'T WORK
- Mapped Address out of PlaceID class, with insertable and updatable as false. -> DON'T WORK
- I've tried to study intern mechanism of HSearch, to try to resolve this problem inside a PreInsertEventListener/PreUpdateEventListener of Hibernate. -> Unsuccessfully.

So, I need to make this work in some way, then my main question is... How can I make it work?

For instance: Is there some intern mechanism/class of Hibernate Search? that I could use inside of a PreInsertEventListener/PreUpdateEventListener (manually way) or somethink like that...

Code of Place class:

```
@Entity
public class Place {

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @EmbeddedId
    private PlaceID id;

    @ContainedIn
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ 
        @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "address_secondId", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "secondId")
    })
    private Address address;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    private String name;
}
```

Code of Address class:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Address {

    @FieldBridge(impl = AddressIdFieldBridge.class)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @EmbeddedId
    private AddressID id;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    private String street;

    @Field(store = Store.YES)
    private String city;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.address")
    private Set<Place> places;
}
```

Versions of dependencies:

```
<hibernate.version>5.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate-search.version>5.8.0.Final</hibernate-search.version>
<lucene.version>5.5.4</lucene.version>
```

Code to update entity and index:

```
@Test
public void givenPlaces_updateAddressIndex(Address address) {
    List<Place> places = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Place place = new Place(new PlaceID((long) new Random().nextInt(500), address));
        place.setName("Place " + new Random().nextInt(500));
        places.add(place);
    }

  placeRepository.save(places);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Updated index manually fullTextSession.index(obj). -> DON'T WORK

If *that* doesn't work, and you're passing the "address" object, it's not related to the `@IndexedEmbedded`/`@ContainedIn`.

> Code to update entity and index:

This code doesn't update the `places` field in `Address`. Hibernate Search may be reindexing `Address`, but since the address currently in the Hibernate session has an empty `places` field, well...

Try adding the new places to `Address.places` in your code, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Yoann! Well, I need to save entity by side of "Place class", and not by side of "Address class". Because I cannot guarantee my team always update places by "Address side".  Is there a way to update "Address index" by "Place" class' side? 
(Obs: My scenario is other, with other classes. But I've made a simple project with Hsearch doc example to simulate it, with same situations)

Comment: @adyjr No, I don't know of a way of automatically updating the non-owning side of an association. It's a frequent issue though: if you have bi-directional associations, you need to keep both sides up-to-date, or you'll run into trouble eventually (not only in Hibernate Search, but also in business code).

Comment: Yoann is right, it's a general requirement of using Hibernate or any other JPA implementation to always update both sides of a relation consistently. With Hibernate you can have this done automatically but only if you enable entity enhancement so to allow it to inject the necessary code in your compiled classes.